# A way to get Column Names as Row Names?

Tags: r, aggregate

My goal is to plot a map with each point representing the year of the highest measured value. So for that I need the year as one value and the Station Name as Row Name.

I get to the point where I get the year of the maximum value for each Station but don´t know how to get the station name as Row Name.

My example is the following:

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:200,2500,rep=TRUE)))
date_df1<-seq(as.Date("1995-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 2500)
test_sto<-cbind(date_df1, df1)
test_sto$date_df1<-as.Date(test_sto$date_df1)
test_sto<-test_sto%>%    dplyr::mutate(     year = lubridate::year(date_df1), 
                                    month = lubridate::month(date_df1),
                                    day = lubridate::day(date_df1))
```

This is my Dataframe, i then applied the following steps:

```
To get all values above the treshold for each year and station:

test_year<-aggregate.data.frame(x=test_sto[2:7] > 120, by = list(test_sto$year), FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE )
```

This works as it should, the nex is the following

```
m <- ncol(test_year)
Value <- rep(NA,m)

for (j in 2:m) {
  idx<- which.max(test_year[,j])
    Value[j] <- test_year[,1][idx]
}
  
test_test<-Value[2:m]
```

At the end of this, I get the following table:

|  | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1996 |
| 2 | 1996 |
| 3 | 1998 |
| 4 | 1996 |
| 5 | 1999 |
| 6 | 1999 |

But instead of the 1,2,3,4,5..I need there my Column Names (X1,X2,X3 etc.):

|  | x |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | 1996 |
| X2 | 1996 |
| X3 | 1998 |
| X4 | 1996 |
| X5 | 1999 |
| X6 | 1999 |

but this is the point where i´m struggeling.
I tried it with the following step:

```
test_year$max<-apply(test_year[2:7], 1, FUN = max)
apply(test_year[2:7], 2, FUN = max)
test_year2<-subset(test_year, ncol(2:7) == max(ncol(2:7)))
```

But i´m just getting an error message saying:

> in max(ncol(2:7)):
> non not-missing Argument for max; give -Inf back<

Maybe someone knows a work around! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'test_test' is just a `vector`.  Its magnitude characterized by `length` and is a one 1 dimensional object which doesn't have `row.names` attribute.  But, we can have `names` attribute

```
names(test_test) <- colnames(test_year)[-1]
```

Comment: That´s not what i´m looking for. I really need to keep the structure, so thats in the list i get is
X1---1996
X2---1996
and so on.

Comment: @André_1090 can you update with your expected ouptut

Comment: @André_1090 I guess you wanted the column name that corresponds to the max value per row and `max.col` does that

Comment: i want for every station (=column) the year in which this particular station got the most exceeds of the treshold. 
so the year is my value what i´m looking for and i need link it to the station, which has to be in the row.

Comment: @André_1090 can you just do `row.names(test_test) <- colnames(test_year)[-1]`

Comment: when i try this i get a error message "Error in rownames<-(x, value)<- try to insert rownames for a object without a dimension"

Comment: @André_1090 I think you have a `vector` then you need `names(test_test) <- colnames(test_year)[-1]`